# Interface higher voltage signal to 5 V pull down input signal circuit using discrete hobby components

Tags: transistors, voltage-divider, 12v, ttl

I have a microcontroller, TTL logic that expects its input to be connected to the ground via a brake lever to tell the microcontroller that the brake has been applied. I believe it uses an internal pull-up resistor as measuring the voltage on the input shows 5 V.

[image: Current microcontroller setup]

Currently my brake lever is connected to a ~12-13.8 V system that runs to brake lights.

[image: Current brake lever setup]

How can I intergrate the two circuits together so that the brake lever lights the brake lights, as well as informs the microcontroller that the brake lever has been pressed? I feel like this circuit would do the job:

[image: Proposed circuit]

1. Would this be an ideal circuit and if not what would be better?
2. What would be good resistor values and transistor to minimise power usage from the 12 V circuit?

Comment: Your transistor is upside down.

Comment: Oops, first time using the diagram software and must have hit flip by mistake. This should be a standard NPN transistor.

Comment: the pullup resistor should not be drawn inside a component ... put it above the switch and above the transistor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fffFTM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The simplified circuit.*

There's no need for your resistor divider. Just set R1 to control the current into Q1's base. It will be about 1 mA if set to 10 kΩ as shown.

I've shown R2 inside your LED lamp as there must be some current-limiting resistor built in.